# Tikz figures in tikzposter environment withouth the prefix "Fig... " caption

Tags: floats, captions, tikzposter

I am working in the `tikzposter` environment and I just would like to have a tikz figure with the caption "Me" without the prefix "Fig. 1". It sounds really simple, but the problem is that due to the implementations of blocks, the standard LaTeX figure environment cannot be used. As a consequence some usual tricks like `\caption*{some text}` or `\usepackage[labelformat=empty]{caption}` do not work properly here (I also tried `\captionsetup[figure]{labelformat=empty}` without any success). According to the `tikzposter` documentation one should use

```
\begin{tikzfigure}[Caption of the figure]
\label{fig:fig1}
Figure
\end{tikzfigure}
```

Thanks a lot for your help!
Sygfried_DA

This is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Because}
\author{we can} 
\date{\today}
\institute{The school of life}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{comment, caption, subcaption}
\usetheme{Default}
\maketitle

\block{Hi}
{
\blindtext
\begin{tikzfigure}[Me]
 \includegraphics[width=0.3\textwidth]{katze.png}
\end{tikzfigure}
}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because tikzfigure doesn't use `\caption`.

```
\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{
  \def \rememberparameter{#1}
  \vspace{10pt}
  \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
  \begin{center}
  }{
    \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
    \else %nothing
    \\[10pt]
    %{\small Fig.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter}
    {\small \rememberparameter}
    \fi
  \end{center}
}
```