# TikZ Poster - need to change Fig. label to Rys. label

Tags: tikzposter

I need to modify figures captions in my TikZ poster, but every common solution does not work.

I just need to modify the word `Fig.`  to `Rys.`  under my pictures. My efforts are as follows, please see text preceded by a percent sign (%):

```
\documentclass[a1paper,14pt,portrait, margin=0pt, colspace=10pt,subcolspace=0pt,blockverticalspace=24pt,innermargin=50pt]{tikzposter}
    \usepackage[latin9,utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    \tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff           
    \usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning}
    
    % \renewcommand*{\figurename}{Rys.}{}  % It does not work :<
    % \renewcommand{\figurename}{Rys.} % not work
    % \makeatletter
    % \renewcommand*{\figurename}{Rys. \thefigure}
    % \makeatother   % Those three line also not work
    
    % \usepackage[figurename=Rys.]{caption}  % Not work
    
    \begin{document}
    
    \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzfigure}[Moja geometria]
    \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{Figures/Sample.png}
    \label{ilu1}
    \end{tikzfigure} 
    \end{center}
    
    \end{document}
```

I am very astonished because for example that line works perfectly:

```
    \renewcommand\refname{Bibliografia}
```

Comment: Have you tried `babel` (or maybe `polyglossia`)?  It seems to work with the accepted answer with the languages I tried.  I'm not sure what language you're trying.  I also wasn't able to get your example to compile, so I'm not sure if `babel` would affect things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures must be placed in a block. Instead if of using `tikzfigure` to define the caption you can use `\captionof{figure}{<text>}` (package `captionof`) . Then `\renewcommand{\figurename}{Rys.}` will work.

[image: a]

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a1paper,14pt,portrait, margin=0pt, colspace=10pt,subcolspace=0pt,blockverticalspace=24pt,innermargin=50pt]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[latin9,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff  
         
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning}

\renewcommand{\figurename}{Rys.} % it works
\usepackage{capt-of} % added <<<<<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \block{}{%  
        \begin{center}
            \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}
            \captionof{figure}{Moja geometria}\label{ilu1}
        \end{center}
    }
    
\end{document}
```

As an alternative you can redefine the `tikzfigure` environment used by the class:

```
% !TeX TS-program = pdflatex

\documentclass[a1paper,14pt,portrait, margin=0pt, colspace=10pt,subcolspace=0pt,blockverticalspace=24pt,innermargin=50pt]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[latin9,utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\tikzposterlatexaffectionproofoff  
         
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric,arrows.meta,positioning}

\renewenvironment{tikzfigure}[1][]{% like https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/315059/161015
    %% #1 Caption
    \def \rememberparameter{#1}
    \vspace{10pt}
    \refstepcounter{figurecounter}
    \begin{center}
    }{%
        \ifx\rememberparameter\@empty
        \else %
        \\[10pt]
        {\small Rys.~\thefigurecounter: \rememberparameter}% changed <<<<       
        \fi
    \end{center}
}

\begin{document}
    \block{}{%  
            \begin{tikzfigure}[Moja geometria]
                 \label{ilu1}
                \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth, keepaspectratio]{example-image}                   
            \end{tikzfigure}        
    }
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Bro what a nice skills. Thanks, you my hero man!